# find x-intercept of a logarithmic function

Tags: logarithms

Find the x-intercept of:

$3-4\log _{10}\left(2x\right) $

My process:

$4\log _{10}\left(2x\right)=3 $

$\log _{10}\left(2x\right)\:=\:\frac{3}{4}$

How would I find the x-intercept from here?

$\log _{10}\left(2x\right)\:=\: \log _{10}\left(?\right)\:$

$2x=?$

$xintercept=\frac{?}{2}$

How do I find the x-intercept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write
$$\log_{10}(2x)=\log_{10}10^{3/4}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $$f(x)=3-4\log _{10}\left(2x\right) $$
and set$$f(x)=0$$
which gives

$$3=4\log _{10}(2x)$$
$$\frac34=\log _{10}(2x)$$
Now $\log_ab=c$ implies $a^c=b$ or like you have done $\log_{10}(2x)=\log_{10}10^{3/4}$
which gives 
$$10^{3/4}=2x$$
$$x=\frac{10^{3/4}}{2}$$

Comment: That is what the OP did in his first step...

Comment: I did that already, 10^x=3/4     So, what is x?